# PHP form submission and AJAX validation

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

**EDIT:** `document.getElementById('submit').disabled='disabled';` does the trick if I put it instead of `return false;` but for some reasons, it also disables the button when the username is NOT taken.

---

Below is basic script to check a username availability.

How can I **prevent the form from being submitted** if a username is already taken?

Ideally i would like to have a JS alert box pop up.

I've tried to add this to the JS but didn't work:

`document.getElementById('submit').disabled`

Also I've tried to add `onclick="return validate();"` to the form itself, but no luck either: the form still can still get submitted.

**HTML**

```
<form id="edit" action="edit.php" method="post">
   <fieldset>       
     <label>Username</label><input type="text" class="input" name="username"      
     id="username"/><span id="status"></span> 
    <button type="submit" id="submit" value="add">Save</button>
   </fielset>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#username").change(function() {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var msgbox = $("#status");

        if (username.length >= 4) {
            $("#status").html('<img src="images/gif/ajax-loading.gif">');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_check.php",
                data: "username=" + username,
                success: function(msg) {

                    if (msg == 'OK') {

                         msgbox.html('<img src="/images/yes.png">');
                         return true;

                    } else {
                        msgbox.html(msg);            
                        return false;

                    }
                }
            });
        } else {

            $("#status").html('<img src="/images/no.png">too long!');
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

`edit.php` and `ajax_check.php` only contain some SQL queries.

Also, some users have JavaScript disabled on their browser, how could I get around this?

Comment: I think `onclick="return validate();"` should do the trick. Where you placed that? it should be in the button element. There is no way to force JS execution, actually the page can be accessed with some download utilities (wget for instance) that don't have any idea what JS is. :)

Comment: @AntoanMilkov I just did as you said and yet, the submit button is still clickable, therefore the form gets submitted. I really need to make sure that no customers can have the same usermame.

Comment: Shouldn't it be on the form `onsubmit` event? Like `<form onsubmit="return validate();">`.

Comment: Change it to:document.getElementById('submit').disabled='disabled' as see what happens

Comment: Can you paste the code for the `function validate` ?

Comment: @jeff, it works ! BUT now, i cant submit the form at all, even when the username is not taken. Also what should I do for users with Javascript disabled. Is there any way to get around this and also use some PHP to disable the button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. Re-enable the button on success and disable it on failure.

```
   if (msg == 'OK') {                       
            msgbox.html('<img src="/images/yes.png">');
            document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;  //enable submit

      } else {                    
            msgbox.html(msg);            
            document.getElementById('submit').disabled = 'disabled';  //disable submit
      }
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works now !! Also what should I do for users with Javascript disabled. Is there any way to get around this and also use some PHP to disable the button ?

Comment: You should not rely only on client side validation. Use proper server side validation too. Client side validation is just for better user experience. Anyone can bypass these validations. You can check if the user is registered or not after form submission and display proper message accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the attribute to the form element

```
onsubmit="return validate();"
```

If JavaScript is disabled then there is nothing you can do about it. This is why it is imperative that you apply data validation/santiation on the server-side.

Comment: thanks but the form can still be submitted. Just to be clear, `onsubmit="return validate();"` should be places within the submit button, right ?

Comment: @BenRifff, no it can be placed in either location, just a different syntax.